# Inflated view's button onClickListener not responding inside RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to get button's `onClickListener` working from inflated layout. I was trying this but nothing happens:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_profile_fragment, null);
Button svBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);

svBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("CLICKED");
    }
});
```

Inside the `RecyclerView` adapter I inflate the original layout in `onCreateViewHolder` which has the layout of the cards, and I am able to interact with it:

```
@Override
public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_card, null);

    return new ItemRowHolder(v);
}
```

But I would like to interact with the button from a different layout (fragment layout). Is that possible, if so how can I achieve that?

Comment: is it possible to interact with button clicks from different layout?

Comment: It looks like it can't register clicks outside of its view `(RecyclerView)`. Because the `my_profile_fragment` inflated layout isn't producing any nullpointers and I can find the button I want to handle clicks of too (which is in `my_profile_fragment` layout).

Answer (score 0):

try `view.getParent()` to get your fragment's parent view.

Comment: view.getParent().findViewById  - not possible. And if cast it to (View) I get nullpointer  View a = (View)view.getParent(); a.findViewById(R.id......

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it, unfortunately is not going to work.

Go to your `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder, int position)`  method, and use the fields of the `viewholder` to directly set your click listener there.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    viewHolder.svBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: svBtn is completely in different layout not related to this RecyclerView. I tried to inflate the different layout in all RecyclerView methods and set onClickListener there but still doesn't work.